# Creating a relationship between a Raphael Path to a Database ID

Tags: javascript, json, svg, raphael, object-relationships

We've created a floor plan with Raphael with specific coordinate paths. Each one of those paths point to a specific seat. The seat is represented by a circle. So when you mouse hover over that circle an action is executed and a tool tip appears. Some specific data for that table needs to be feed with Ajax from the database to that tool tip that is displayed

On the Admin side we will create a Database with specific info for each seat i.e. seat#(seat #4, seat #105A etc...) seating area(mezzanine, first floor, etc...) and a few other data points that go inside the tool tip.

Our problem is that we do not to know how to assign an ID to each Path (circle) and tie that to the data points on the admin side.

What we want is that when we create the seat data on the admin side, lets say seat #10 in the mezzanine section, we want to create a way for that path to identify itself with that specific seat # and pull all the specific data to its tool tip.

So we would like to know how to build that relationship between the Raphael coordinates paths that represent our seats, with the seat data in our SQL 2008 database.

Comment: When you create the seat you can apply an Id to the object. When you subsequently interact with it the action handler you applied will "know" what the I'd is

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.data(key, [value])` to associate custom information with any element.  Example from the documentation:

```
for (var i = 0, i < 5, i++) {
    paper.circle(10 + 15 * i, 10, 10)
         .attr({fill: "#000"})
         .data("i", i)
         .click(function () {
            alert(this.data("i"));
         });
}
```

Using this, just generate your database id however you want and then add this as metadata on the object.  On `mouseover()` or whatever, just read the id back from the element.

Answer (score 0):

To finish the comment I added.
You would be able to code alert(this.id);
Also see the function Element.data